# AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'find_all' Python Web Scraping w/ Beautiful Soup

Tags: python, list, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I have two problems. First of all, I get the error that is listed in the title "AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'find_all'" whenever I activate this line of code. Secondly, I want to access one more statistic on this specific website as well. So, firstly, my code is below. This is meant to gather names from a website, trim off the excess, then take those names, insert them into a URL, and take two statistics. The first statistic that I am taking is on line 22, which is the source of the error. And the second statistic is in HTML and is also going to be listed after my code.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re

res = requests.get('https://plancke.io/hypixel/guild/name/GBP')
soup = BeautifulSoup(res.text, 'lxml')

memberList = []
skillAverageList = []

for i in soup.select('.playerInfo'):
    memberList.append(i.text)

memberList = [e[37:-38] for e in memberList]

members = [re.sub("[A-Z][^A-Z]+$", "", member.split(" ")[1]) for member in memberList]
print(members)

for i in range(len(memberList) + 1):
    player = memberList[i]
    skyLeaMoe = requests.get('https://sky.lea.moe/stats/' + str(player))
    skillAverageList.append(soup.find("div", {"id":"additional_stats_container"}).find_all("div",class_="additional-stat")[-2].get_text(strip=True))

pprint(skillAverageList)
```

Below is the second statistic that I would like to scrape from this website as well (in HTML). This specific statistic is attributed to this specific site, but the code above will hopefully be able to cycle through the entire list (https://sky.lea.moe/stats/Igris/Apple).

```
<span class="stat-name">Total Slayer XP: </span> == $0
<span class ="stat-value">457,530</span>
```

I am sorry if this is a lot, I have almost no knowledge of HTML and any attempt for me to learn it has been a struggle. Thanks in advance to anyone this reaches.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that this site doesn't have a `div` with the `id` of `"additional_stats_container"`, and therefore `soup.find("div", {"id":"additional_stats_container"})` returns None.

Upon inspecting the HTML of this URL with a browser, I couldn't find such a `div`.

Answer (score 0):

This script will print all names and their `Total Slayer XP`:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


url = 'https://plancke.io/hypixel/guild/name/GBP'
stats_url = 'https://sky.lea.moe/stats/'

soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).content, 'html.parser')

for a in soup.select('td a[href*="/hypixel/player/stats/"]'):
    s = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(stats_url + a['href'].split('/')[-1]).content, 'html.parser')
    total_slayer_xp = s.select_one('span:contains("Total Slayer XP") + span')
    print('{:<30} {}'.format(a.text, total_slayer_xp.text if total_slayer_xp else '-'))
```

Prints:

```
[MVP+] Igris                   457,530
[VIP] Kutta                    207,665
[VIP] mistercint               56,455
[MVP+] zouce                   1,710,540
 viellythedivelon              30
[MVP+] Louis7864               141,670
[VIP] Broadside1138            292,240
[VIP+] Babaloops               40
[VIP+] SparkleDuck9            321,290
[VIP] TooLongOfAUserNa         423,700

...etc.
```